# How to subtract two date as datetime2 format in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I create a method to subtract two dates and this is equal to in real date as format datetime2(7) in sql server 2008. 
For example ,I create this method:
`Delete from TblMessage
Where MDateTime<((SELECT     TOP (1)MDateTime FROM  TblMessage ORDER BY MDateTime DESC)- ('2013-10-04 16:47:56.0000000'))`

but it is not working  .I want to result of subtract two date like this:

```
MDateTime1:2013-10-05 16:47:56.0000000
MDateTime2:2013-09-04 16:47:56.0000000
Result:2013-01-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

Result=MDateTime1-MDateTime2
How can I do this. Thanks...

Comment: Unable to execute the above query in my sand box.

Comment: I explained it above. This method is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this?

select DATEADD( day, datediff(day,GETDATE(), getdate() - 10), GETDATE() ) ;

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF(dayofyear,MDateTime1,MDateTime2)` AS Result

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: This method give me number of days .I do not want to it..I want to get result as datetime

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand at all what you're hoping to see as the result. You want to subtract one date from another and get a date as the answer. So somehow subtracting Sept. 4 from Oct. 5 = Jan. 1? That doesn't make sense to me. Maybe some additional explanation with a better example would help out here.

Comment: I want delete data from database by using datetime .I have a table name of TblMessage this table have a column as name MDateTime .I need to delete data except last month(30days) from last data  and I need use MDatetime as datetime format sql server .OK

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE 
    @DATE1 DATETIME = '2013-10-05 16:47:56.000',
    @DATE2 DATETIME = '2013-09-04 17:37:42.000',
    @DATEDIFF AS INT,
    @BASEDATE DATETIME;

    -- USE WHAT EVER DATE YOU WISH TO BE YOUR BASE DATE

    SET @BASEDATE = '1/1/1900';

    SET @DATEDIFF = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @DATE2, @DATE1);

    SELECT @DATE1,@DATE2,@DATEDIFF, DATEADD(SECOND,@DATEDIFF,@BASEDATE)
```

Thus a scalar function could be created like this...

```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.sf_GetMeasureDate
    (
        @EndDate DATETIME,
        @StartDate DATETIME,
        @BaseDate DATETIME
    )
    RETURNS DATETIME
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DATEDIFF AS INT
        SET @DATEDIFF = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @StartDate, @EndDate);
        Return DATEADD(SECOND,@DATEDIFF,@BASEDATE)
    END
    GO
```

Then within you regular SELECT statement you can call the function as such.

```
SELECT dbo.sf_GetMeasureDate('2013-10-05 16:47:56.000','2013-09-04 17:37:42.000','1/1/1900')
```

or within an existing query:

```
SELECT dbo.sf_GetMeasureDate([fld1],[fld2],'1/1/1900')
```